# Passing string value to site to be authenticated iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, authentication, sdk

I'm trying to set this up where the user gives username and password in-app, and the app sends these strings to a server (http://www.brsgolf.com/landb/) to be authenticated. Then the app allows the user access some content or whatever.

The thing is, I want it all done in-app, I don't even want WebView's. What is the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advice you to use [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html)